# How can i access current session data outside django view function?

Tags: python, django, session

I am using SessionStore object to store session data, how can i get current session data from Session table without using pk as we dont know pk of record stored in table.

Here is the code

ldap.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
s = SessionStore()

class LDAPPBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        **s['memberOf']** = "Star Group" #**setting session**
        s.create()
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
**s = Session.objects.get(pk="")** #**how can i know current logged in user session pk???**
class TokenObtainPairPatchedSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data['attr'] = attrs
        **data['memberOf'] = s** # **How can i get current session data here??**
        return data
```

How can i achieve this???

Comment: Can't you access the `request` object with your serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the request in serializer because generic view passes request to serializer through [context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```
class TokenObtainPairPatchedSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data['attr'] = attrs
        session = self.context.get('request').session 
        # rest of the code
        return data
```

You can access it because [`TokenObtainPairView`](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html) is derived from [`GenericAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview).

Comment: My problem got fixed, i changed to authenticate(self, request, *args, **kwargs) in ldap.py and i can use like request.session["memberOf"] along with your solution session = self.context.get('request').session, Thank you.